# What's the Derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, tensor-products, partial-derivative

What is the derivative (gradient) of $$\operatorname{vec}(W)^\top
\left[\sum_i (ue_i^\top)\otimes(e_ie_i^\top) + \sum_j(e_je_j^\top)\otimes(ue_j^\top) - 2I\otimes I\right]
\operatorname{vec}(FF^\top),\tag{3}
$$ where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th vector in the canonical basis and $u=\sum_ie_i=(1,1,\ldots,1)^\top$
where "$\otimes$" denotes the Kronecker product (tensor product) with respect to the rectangular matrix $F$? and $W$ is a constant matrix. The above term can also be simplified as $\sum_{ijl}(F_{il}-F_{jl})^2W_{ij}$ which is a much simpler expression. What would the derivative be? All the above entries are real while $F$ is a rectangular matrix. Also please refer to : [Represent in a matrix form: $\sum_{ijl}(F_{il}-F_{jl})^2W_{ij}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404156/represent-in-a-matrix-form-sum-ijlf-il-f-jl2w-ij) for the details on simplification/algebra.

Comment: The whole left side of the expression is independent of $F$, so all you need to do is calculate the vector derivative of $\mathrm{vec}(FF^T)$.

Comment: Considering the expression on the left to be $C$, the derivative of $CFF^T$ would be $(C+C^T)F$, I guess? Now with $C\operatorname{vec}(FF^T)$, am confused..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the derivative, it is much easier to work with your original expression $S=\sum_{ijl}(F_{il}-F_{jl})^2W_{ij}$. Note that, for fixed indices $I$ and $J$,
\begin{align*}
S = &\text{ terms that do not involve } F_{IJ}\\
&+\ (F_{IJ} - F_{IJ})^2 W_{II}
+ \sum_{j\neq I} (F_{IJ} - F_{jJ})^2 W_{Ij}
+ \sum_{i\neq I} (F_{iJ} - F_{IJ})^2 W_{iI}\\
= &\text{ terms that do not involve } F_{IJ}\\
&+\ \sum_{k\neq I} (F_{IJ} - F_{kJ})^2 W_{Ik}
+ \sum_{k\neq I} (F_{kJ} - F_{IJ})^2 W_{kI}.
\end{align*}
Let $K = W-W^T$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial F_{IJ}}
=&2\sum_{k\neq I} (F_{IJ} - F_{kJ}) W_{Ik}
+ 2\sum_{k\neq I} (F_{kJ} - F_{IJ}) W_{kI}\\
=&2\sum_{k\neq I} (F_{IJ} - F_{kJ}) (W_{Ik}-W_{kI})\\
=&2\sum_{k\neq I} (F_{IJ} - F_{kJ}) K_{Ik}\\
=&2\sum_k (F_{IJ} - F_{kJ}) K_{Ik}\\
=&2F_{IJ}\sum_k K_{Ik} - 2\sum_k K_{Ik}F_{kJ}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial F_{ij}}\right)
=2F\circ(KE) - 2KF
$$
where $E$ is the matrix with the same size as $F$ and all entries equal to $1$.

Comment: Wonderful answer!

Comment: also that's the Hadamard Product between $F$ and $KE$. Right?

Comment: @user75402 Yes, it's the Hadamard product.

Comment: There is a sign error in the second term of the derivative.  The derivative of $(F_{kJ}-F_{IJ})^2$ with respect to $F_{IJ}$ is $-2\,(F_{kJ}-F_{IJ})$.  However, the form of the final result is correct, if you redefine $K=W+W^T$.