# What is $\frac{\partial\det(L)}{\partial x_i}$, where $L_{i,j} = \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2} {2\sigma ^2} \right)$ using Jacobi's formula?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

We have  $n \times n$ matrix $L$, given by the following Gaussian kernel
$$L_{i,j} = \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2} {2\sigma ^2} \right)$$

where the points  $x_i$  and $x_j$  are real numbers that can be thought as positions of points $i$ and $j$. ( $L$ can be seen as a covariance matrix, describing covariance depending on distance between points. The higher distance between points $i$ and $j$ the less the covariance.)

I am interested in finding
$$ \frac{\partial\det(L)}{\partial x_i}$$

From [Matrix Book](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf), can I use Jacobi's formula?
$$\frac{\partial\det(L)}{\partial x}= \det (L) \operatorname{Tr}\left( L^{-1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\right).$$

Is it correct that $\frac{\partial\det(L)}{\partial x_i} = \det (L) \operatorname{Tr}\left( L^{-1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i}\right)$

where $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i}$ is the matrix given by the terms $\frac{\partial L_{k,l}}{\partial x_i}=0$ for $k,l \neq i$

and $\frac{\partial L_{i,j}}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial L_{j,i}}{\partial x_i}=-\frac{(x_i-x_j)}{ \sigma ^2} L_{i,j}$?

Answer (score 1):

Collect the $x_i$ vectors into a single matrix
$$X = \big[\matrix{x_1&x_2\ldots&x_n}\big]$$
Following [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240429/pairwise-distance-matrix), define the Gram matrix and extract its main diagonal into a vector
$$G=X^TX,\quad g=\operatorname{diag}(G)$$
Take the log of $L$ and differentiate
$$\eqalign{
L &= \exp\left(\frac{2G -g{\tt1}^T -{\tt1}g^T}{2\sigma^2}\right) \\
2\sigma^2\log(L) &= 2G -g{\tt1}^T -{\tt1}g^T \\
2\sigma^2\left(\frac{dL}{L}\right) &= 2\,dG -dg\,{\tt1}^T -{\tt1}\,dg^T \\
dL &= \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}L\odot(2\,dG - dg\,{\tt1}^T - {\tt1}\,dg^T) \\
}$$
For later convenience, define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= \left(\frac{\phi}{2\sigma^2}\right)\\
R &= L\odot L^{-T}
 \quad &\big({\rm Hadamard\,Product}\big)\\
P &= \Big(\operatorname{Diag}(R{\tt1})-R\Big) 
 \quad &\big({\rm Laplacian\,of\,}R\big) \\
}$$
Start with the formula for the derivative of the determinant and substitute $dL$ from above.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \det(L) \\
d\phi &= \phi\,L^{-T}:dL \\
 &= \phi\,L^{-T}:(2\,dG - dg\,{\tt1}^T - {\tt1}\,dg^T)\odot\frac{L}{2\sigma^2} \\
 &=\alpha R:\left(2\,dG -dg\,{\tt1}^T -{\tt1}\,dg^T\right) \\
 &= 2\alpha R:dG - 2R{\tt1}:dg \\
 &= 2\alpha R:dG - 2\alpha R{\tt1}:\operatorname{diag}(dG) \\
 &= 2\alpha \Big(R -\operatorname{Diag}(R{\tt1})\Big):dG \\
 &= -2\alpha P:dG \\
 &= -2\alpha P:(X^TdX+dX^TX) \\
 &= -4\alpha P:X^TdX \\
 &= -4\alpha XP:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
 &= -4\alpha XP \\
 &= -\left(\frac{2\phi}{\sigma^2}\right)XP \\
}$$
So that's the formula for the gradient wrt the $X$ matrix.

To find the gradient with respect one of its columns, multiply by the standard basis vector $e_i$
$$\eqalign{
x_i &= Xe_i \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}
  &= \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}\right)e_i
 \;=\; -\left(\frac{2\phi}{\sigma^2}\right)XPe_i \\
}$$
**NB:** In several steps, a colon was used as a product notation for the trace operator, i.e. $$\eqalign{
A:B &= \operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)
}$$
Use was also made of the fact that $\{G,L,M,P\}$ 
are all symmetric matrices.

The matrix $R=\big(L\odot L^{-T}\big)$ is known as the *relative gain array* and has some interesting uses in control theory. One of its properties is $R{\tt1}={\tt1}$, which allows some terms to be simplified. 
$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{Diag}(R{\tt1}) &= I \\
P &= \big(I-R\big) \\
}$$

Comment: thanks a lot. However, I think  you made an error here, it does not seem correct that  $ -4P:X^TdX = -4XP:dX $

Comment: $x_i$  is  not a vector, but a scalar

Comment: If $x_i$ is a scalar that just means that $X$ is a (row) vector. Also, the cyclic property of the trace allows the terms of a colon product to be re-arranged in _exactly_ the way you've highlighted.

Comment: thanks Greg, my question then why not using Jacobi formula, I see that it applies directly to my case (see also the description where I suggested the solution). Here Jacobi formula [link] (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214908/proof-for-the-derivative-of-the-determinant-of-a-matrix). I think the result will be the same using your derivation or using Jacobi.

Comment: I used the Jacobi formula in the very **first** step, i.e. $$d\phi = \phi L^{-T}:dL$$

Comment: Thanks, but I can not see why the trace did disappear from your end result. I mean how from a trace  $\partial \phi = -4\alpha XP:dX $ we arrived in the next line to a product of matrices $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}= -4\alpha XP $. 
The Jacobi formula has the trace, $$\frac{\partial\det(L)}{\partial x}= \det (L) \operatorname{Tr}\left( L^{-1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\right).$$.

Comment: The Jacobi formula, in the form you've written it, **only** works when $x$ is a scalar. If $x$ is a vector or matrix, then the quantity inside the trace function becomes a 3rd or 4th order tensor. How would you define the trace of a tensor?